# submit contact form and pass variables to page redirected in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, payment-gateway, contact-form

In wordpress I have a form using contact form 7. Upon filling the form and submitting I need it to carry variables e.g. name, address, email and amount and redirect to third party payment gateway page (hdfc in my case) so that users can just fill the form and make the payment in one go...

Woo-commerce involve 2-3 stesps i.e. add to cart, checkout, proceed to pay etc. I just wanted to fill the form and with filled information pass variables to payment page directly.

Any quick help much appreciated in advance...
Thanks!
Ranjan

Comment: what you have tried so far?where you got stuck?

Comment: if you search in google only you will get more ideas about pass values to payment page.

Comment: Thanks lalithkuar, but I posted this question only after giving up with the helps available on google. Looking forward for a relevant solutions.. Thanks anyway...